# retrieve data using json and jquery ajax call no work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm triyng to retrieve JSON format data using `$.ajax` method of jquery from a php page, I get this error `parseerror` when the code runs, but if I see the response of the server with firebug it's Ok.

Here's my script code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "php/selectedObjectRequest.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {},
    success: function(data) {
        var prova = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        alert(prova.museum);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus);
    }
});
```

And that's my server side code:

```
$arrayToEncode = array(
     'museum'     => 'bellearti',
     'atwork'     => 'davide',
     'beaconCode' => '78888',
     'qrCode'     => '2252222'
);
echo json_encode($arrayToEncode);
```

How I can solve?

**solved:**

My error was an `echo` to test before 
`echo json_encode($arrayToEncode);`
pay attention.

Comment: As an aside, if you aren't set on using `POST` (and you might not be if there are no params), you can use `$.getJSON` instead of `$.ajax`. Arguments are exactly the same, but then you can drop explicitly setting `type` and `dataType`.

Comment: Check if you have valid JSON [http://jsonlint.com/]

Comment: my json is valid and it's this:   `{
    "museum": "bellearti",
    "atwork": "davide",
    "beaconCode": "78888",
    "qrCode": "2252222"
}

Comment: If the jQuery error handler is reporting a parseerror, then you aren't sending back valid JSON. Presumably you have other characters before and/or after it. Check the Net tab to see what you are really sending.

Comment: you're right man...thank's a lot!! i add an echo before echo JSON and that's was the error thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter `data` in your `success` handler will be preprocessed because you told jQuery that the `dataType` was JSON. You should be able to just use `data.museum`. To make sure, `console.log(data);` to see what it is.

Comment: thanks for your answer but , i try to use data.musum but continue to get parseerror

Comment: So your `success` handler looks like this:  `success: function(data) { alert(data.museum);}` right? (sorry, comments don't allow line breaks)

Comment: yes i update my success handler like your but nothing change

Comment: What is the error you're getting (in full if possible)? If it's in jQuery, then you have an issue with the return from the server.

Comment: the errror the i get from the jquery error handler is **parseerror**

Comment: @Pekka — What's the relevance of that? The OP just said the jQuery error handler was being fired, so the code in the success handler never gets touched.

Comment: @Quentin i dont know now as far as i can see i am asking Kevin to not 'Quentin' besides i just want to show him that his code does work maybe it is a different problem he can check at.

Comment: @sdrabb because your `error` handler is being called, it appears that you do have a server-side issue. Chances are that some other character is being leaked. Load the URL of the JSON up in a new tab, view source, there is something there that is killing the JSON and preventing it from parsing. Do you have a publicly accessible URL you can share?

Comment: i solve thanks my error was an echo to thest before the echo of encode_json

Comment: Awesome. So it was a combination of broken JSON and parsing a pre-parsed return. Been there myself many times. Good luck with your project. *(if you like any of the answers, feel free to click the tick beside it)*

Answer (score 1):

the answer is: 
change prova.museum to data.museum

```
$.ajax({
    url: "php/selectedObjectRequest.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {},
    success: function(data) {

       alert(data.museum); // add data.museum instant of prova.museum
    },
    error: function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tyweL1o8/)

Change the format

```
$arrayToEncode[] = array(
    'museum' => 'bellearti',
    'atwork' => 'davide',
    'beaconCode' => '78888',
    'qrCode' => '2252222');

echo json_encode($arrayToEncode, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

So that you can call the return value like

```
for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
    console.log(data[j].museum);
    console.log(data[j].atwork);
    console.log(data[j].beaconCode);
    console.log(data[j].qrCode);
}
```

Comment: Why would you add an extra layer of array?

Comment: That seems entirely pointless … while not addressing the problem at all.

Comment: @Quentin Well i would have copied the answer of Kevin above if i didnt. I just want to suggest another answer if he wanted to. Plus i think it is addressing the problem because it is a completely different approach yet giving the same result

Comment: Wrapping the data is an array is a different approach, but one that adds a pointless layer of complication without fixing the problem at all. You might also be suggesting dropping the call to `parseJSON`, but you don't say that explicitly, that's the only thing in the answer that might help at all, and it *is* exactly the same approach as the earlier answer.

Comment: @Quentin as you said yourself this is a different approach my point is just to give another option that the first answer this might not be the best answer but in any case it can be an answer.As it is a different approach this may come in handy according to the needs, for future reference

Comment: Guys come on, be nice :-)

Comment: While wrapping the data in the array is a different approach, it isn't a different approach to solving the problem. It doesn't help at all. It is a red herring. It is a waste of people's time to read it.

Comment: @KevinNagurski thank you mate you did the great going on the answer you deserve the UP and the VOTE.. :)

Comment: @Quentin Ok I Believe you now but i will not delete the answer if you may because one of these days someone might come here and needs a way to get data from a multidimensional array. Sorry to waste some of your time reading the answer

Comment: It doesn't seem very likely that they would find *this* question if they wanted to get data out of a multidimensional array. This question isn't asking about multidimensional arrays. There are plenty of other questions that are.

Answer (score -2):

Try using this:

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
```

This usually works for me.

Comment: Why would renaming the variable from `prova` to `parsed` help?

Comment: @Quentin he's actually using the native `JSON` class from the browser instead of jQuery's version (though newer versions of jQuery will actually proxy to the native version, so I suppose you have a point)

Comment: Oh, I hadn't noticed that. That's the problem with answers that are expressed in terms of Spot-The-Difference instead of explaining why the original code doesn't work and why the new code fixes the problem.